# Where to register for C# events?

Tags: c#, events

I am currently transitioning from VB to C# and am having some issues with regards to registering my interest in an event.

When using VB it was simply a case of specifying that a method `Handles` and event, often this was generated by using the object events list.  While I can easily use the `Class.event += delegate` in C# I am unsure where the best place is to place the code to do this.

Am I best placing it inside of the `InitializeComponent()` as per the generated code (say if you select the event in the from designer) or should I place it inside the constructor for better readability/maintenance.  If inside the constructor, should it be before or after the call to `InitializeComponent()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are doing WinForm development (judging from InitializeComponent() function mentioned), usually you assign the handler using Visual Studio. You look up the properties of your control, click on the lightning icon to get the list of all events, find your event, and either double click on it (to create a new handler), or select existing handler from the list. Visual Studio will add the wiring of this in the generated code, so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: I saw you could still do this but I also have classes from a DLL that raise events and I have to register for these via code.

Comment: If you need to register for events from some business objects, I would keep it separate from the UI events (because they serve completely different purpose). Ideally do it in your business logic classes, if it is not possible than in e.g. Load event handler of your form.

Answer (score 3):

I always create a private method called `Init()` and place it there, and then call that method from the constructor or the Form_Load event handler.  It's semantically better, IMO, than doing it within the constructor proper.  And you don't want to place it within `InitializeComponent()`, because next time you change something in your designer it's likely to delete any manually-added code there.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes Visual Studio's designer can mess up the code, so adding the event handlers within `InitializeComponent` can create a headache, it would be better to do it something like this

```
public Form1(){
   InitializeComponent();
   WireUpEvents();
}

public void WireUpEvents(){
   this.fooEvent += new EventHandler(foo_handler);
   .... etc ....
}
```

And make sure that you remove the event handlers in the Form's Dispose function also...

```
public void UnWireEvents(){
   this.fooEvent -= new EventHandler(foo_handler);
   .... etc ....
}
```

As you design the form, Visual Studio will change the code within the `InitializeComponent()` method located in `form.design.cs`, so it is imperative that you do not manually edit this code..

Answer (score 1):

It depends, but most of the time, yes.

Use InitializeComponent when you want the event to be hooked for the entire duration of the Form (I'm assuming you're talking about Forms/UserControls/etc.).  In other cases, you'll want finer grained control of when the Event is handled.

Keep in mind that you'll want to unhook all of these events (using the -= syntax) when you're Disposing the Form, or no longer want to handle the event.  Keeping the event handler delegates attached is one of the most common managed memory leaks around.

Comment: I have noted that if I use the lighting icon to generate a += no corresponding -= is generated.  Where should I be putting these?

Surely once the reference is out of scope the GC should be managing this
?

Comment: You need to override the Dispose method and unhook them.  Assuming that your components are self-contained (i.e. the path to the GC roots don't include any objects that haven't gone out of scope) you are correct -- this will get GC'd.  However, if you use static handlers, or expose these controls where other events get attached (but not detached), they never "go out of scope", giving you your managed memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* manually add code to the `InitializeComponent()` method.  This method is code generated, so as soon as you change your form, any logic that you've added manually to this method will be wiped out.

I usually add a method to handle the Form's `Load` event and put my event registrations there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `InitializeComponent()` method you're using the designer so you can bind events directly in the designer if you like.  To do this, click the lightning bolt icon in the properties window and you'll see a list of all the events for the selected object.  You can just type the name of the event in there and it'll create the code for you.

If you're not a fan of the designer, bind them after your `InitializeComponent` call and make sure you detach them when you're done (in `Dispose()`).

Answer (score 0):

2 ways of doing this.  You can either create you own method which you call in your Constructor which in turn creates the Event Handler, or you can just place them in your Constructor.  Probably a good idea to remove the Event Handlers in your Finalizer/Destructor code.

Answer (score 0):

I would place it after InitializeComponent, since you might be registering events against a child control/object, like a button, and you will want to be sure the object has been created already.

There will be cases where you wire up to events dynamically/conditionally in other places, such as in response to some other event.